# Spring CrudRepository - 'not equals' condition for child table(which is as List)

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I've two entity with @OneToMany relationship

First Entity

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = SchemaConstant.RESCHEDULE_TABLE_NAME)
    public class RescheduleRequestEntity extends BaseEntity {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "RESCHEDULE_ID_GEN")
      @SequenceGenerator(
          name = "RESCHEDULE_ID_GEN",
          allocationSize = 1,
          sequenceName = SchemaConstant.RESCHEDULE_SEQUENCE_NAME)
      private Long id;

      private String adviseNo;
      private LocalDate adviseDate;
      private Long customerId;

      @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
      private AdviceStatus status;

      @OneToMany(mappedBy = "reschedule", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
      private List<RescheduleDetailEntity> accountDetails;

    }
```

Second Entity

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "RESCHEDULE_DETAILS")
    public class RescheduleDetailEntity extends BaseEntity {

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "RESCHEDULE_DETAILS_ID_GEN")
      @SequenceGenerator(
          name = "RESCHEDULE_DETAILS_ID_GEN",
          allocationSize = 1,
          sequenceName = "S_RESCHEDULE_DETAILS")
      private Long id;

      @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
      @JoinColumn(name = "ACCOUNT_ID", nullable = false)
      private AccountEntity account;

      @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
      private AdviceStatus status;

      @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
      private TenureType tenureType;

      private Integer tenure;

      @ManyToOne
      @JoinColumn(name = "ADVISE_ID")
      private RescheduleDetailEntity reschedule;
    }
```

AND Enum

```
    public enum AdviceStatus {
      OPEN,
      ACTIVE,
      CLOSE
    }
```

I want to fetch data with condition Like

```
    SELECT *
      FROM RESCHEDULEREQUESTENTITY R, RESCHEDULEDETAILENTITY D
     WHERE R.ID = :PID
       AND D.ADVISEID = R.ID
       AND D.STATUS <> "CLOSE"
```

"Data fetch from RescheduleRequestEntity with data from RescheduleDetailEntity where RescheduleDetailEntity.status is not equal "CLOSE" where "Status" is Enum type".

I create a JPA Repository class like following for fetch data

```
    @Repository
    public interface RescheduleRequestRepository
        extends JpaRepository<RescheduleRequestEntity, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor {

      Optional<RescheduleRequestEntity> findByAdviseNo(String adviceNo);

      Optional<RescheduleDetailEntity> findByIdAndAccountDetails_StatusNot(
          Long adviceId, AdviceStatus status);
    }
```

but it's not fetch data with my desired condition,it's not ignore data which have Status "CLOSE"

Comment: Try renaming `findByIdAndAccountDetails_StatusNot` to `findByIdAndAccountDetailsAndStatusNot`  or `findByIdAndAccountDetailsAndStatusNotIn`

Comment: Thanks @Shariq, but I've try it in past and it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it a custom query using @Query annotation.